# Any recommendation for educational Chanukah video?

Tags: history, product-recommendation, chanuka

I am looking for video clips about the Chanukah story that my kids - seven to ten years old - can watch. I thought there would be many, but it's not easy to find any good one. I prefer video in Hebrew, but English, French or German is also fine.

It would be great if you can share a link in the Internet or DVD that I can buy.

Happy Chanukah!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Dav! Consider learning more about the site, from this short Beginners' Guide: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite fond of [this](http://www.chabad.org/kids/article_cdo/aid/1050433/jewish/Maccabees.htm) video, which is recording of a stage play that the Jewish Children's Museum put on in 2006. It's very entertaining, while maintaining the spirit of the story. There are a few parts that are put in for giggles and grins, but they're obvious and most children would understand that's not actually what happened. I've known many young kids who have learned a lot from this video, including my younger siblings.

(Courtesy of Chabad.org Kids)

Answer (score 1):

TorahLive is a great source for authentic Jewish material for kids (and grown-ups). They have a video called [Hanukah, the ultimate dedication](https://torahlive.com/courses/chanukah-the-ultimate-dedication/) which you will hopefully enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

[*Reindeer and Latkes: Aren't The Winter Holidays Suspiciously Similar? Is Hanukkah just a Jewish version of Christmas? What makes Hanukkah special?*](http://www.aish.com/h/c/mm/Reindeer-and-Latkes-Arent-The-Winter-Holidays-Suspiciously-Similar.html)

by Rabbi David Fohrman

Comment: This is for 7 year olds?

Comment: Thank you for a wonderful video. It seems to be for older ones than mine, but kids grow every year. :)

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend [*The Lights*, by Gesher (1985)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WkG6gX7lcE). (Then have a talk with the kids about the symbolism.)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation for this video clip. We will try to watch it and talk about the holiday as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In French.  [for  children Super wonderful](http://www.jplanete.com/fr/jeux-et-jouets-hanouka/l-incroyable-histoire-de-hanouka-cd-audio.html)

Comment: Thanks for recommending this audio cd. I definitely consider buying one.